# Passing value of variable to next page using post method

Tags: php, post

In a code below I want to pass variable `$user_id` to next page using post method suppose my next page is `followers.php` . The whole code is link itself i want to put post method in it so that on clicking the link, variable is also passed to `follower.php` . Don't want to use sessions.

```
<a href='follower.php' style='text-decoration:none;'>
<h2>Followers</h2>
<?php
$checkfollowers = "SELECT * FROM follow_user WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$resultfollowers = mysqli_query($con,$checkfollowers);
echo mysqli_num_rows($resultfollowers );
?></a>
```

I guess code for post method is correct:

```
 <form method="get" action="follower.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="varname" value="user_id">
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

So how to put this post method inside the other code so on clicking, `follower.php` is opened and variable is also passed to this page.

Comment: `$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];`

Comment: Also consider some protectinon from SQL injection https://www.wikiwand.com/en/SQL_injection

Comment: Simplest way in your case would be $user_id = (int) $_POST['user_id'];

Comment: the form's method should be `post` not `get`. Then for the hidden field, use  `<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $userid;?>">` just make sure when grabbing the user_id, later via post to validate $_POST['user_id'] is indeed a valid user_id.

Answer (score 0):

You are using GET method. Change it to

```
<form method="POST" action="follower.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="user_id">
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Also change the name to user_id of the hidden field. Now receive as

```
<?php

$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$checkfollowers = "SELECT * FROM follow_user WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$resultfollowers = mysqli_query($con,$checkfollowers);
echo mysqli_num_rows($resultfollowers );
?>
```

Note: Above query is vulnerable to SQLI. Better to use Prepared statements.

Comment: @Epodax, OP wrote `using post method`

Comment: My mistake, seems like I interpreted his question / text :)

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about post method but in your code you are using the method GET. You might want to consider to change this into POST. This way the stuff filled out in the form will not enter the URL. (bit more secure). After this you could call the global variable $_POST['user_id']

Answer (score 0):

A link cannot POST data, only GET.

use:

```
<a href='follower.php?user_id=1' style='text-decoration:none;'>
```

and in follower.php file:

```
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
```

Comment: you were right link doesn't work with post but is sending variable by get method, can you please tell `follower.php?user_id=1` here what I will be sending instead of 1, $user_id?

Comment: for get $user_id you use $_SESSION or get it from post form.